# Polynomial interpolation of corrected lognormal distribution

Tags: returns, brownian-motion, expected-return, lognormal, asset-returns

Can anyone provide a formula for a polynomial interpolation of the corrected lognormal distribution used to model returns traditionally resulting from the wrong Brownian motion generated model? Obviously I am only looking for a sufficiently good approximation. Thanks.